# Splitting a list in python into three separate lists

Tags: python, list, split

So I need to split a list in python, My txt file looks like this:

```
  ip,user,password
  ip,user,passord
```

and so on. I already read in the list, and I can split it, but I will only get the first ip. I would like to be able to split the list into three seperate lists, one for ip, user and password. Here is my code so far:

```
def OpenFile():
   read = [line.strip() for line in open("People.txt" , 'r')
   return read

jh = OpenFile()
sp = [i.split(',',1)[0] for i in jh]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can split them by `,` and then `zip` the split lists together like this

```
with open("People.txt" , 'r') as inFile:
   ips, users, passwords = zip(*[line.strip().split(",") for line in inFile])
```

Now, if you print the variables, you will get

```
print ips, users, passwords
('ip', 'ip') ('user', 'user') ('password', 'passord')
```

Comment: I am getting the error, "To many Values to unpack, Value Error"

Comment: @aaronbill Are you sure your file doesn't have nothing more than ip, users and passwords? Can you please show some actual data?

Comment: Oh sorry, i just got it, i change the format of it alittle to make it work, thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> lines = ['ip,user,password', 'ip,user,passord']
>>> rows = [line.strip().split(',') for line in lines]  # `lines` -> file object
>>> rows
[['ip', 'user', 'password'], ['ip', 'user', 'passord']]
>>> zip(*rows)  # Output will be different in Python 3.x
[('ip', 'ip'), ('user', 'user'), ('password', 'passord')]
>>> ip, user, password = zip(*rows)
>>> ip
('ip', 'ip')
>>> user
('user', 'user')
>>> password
('password', 'passord')
```